# Temporary "USB" files in Ubuntu?

Tags: usb

Browsers normally store temp files; does the OS (Ubuntu 13.10, or its bundled image application) also store temporary files of images opened from a USB stick?

I dropped and broke my USB stick with holiday pictures on it, but before that I had looked at them on my machine, without backing them up to the computer. Any chance those files (even if smaller versions of them) are lying somewhere on my computer's file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it stores thumbnails, but I don't know whether images from USB are cached. Look in the ~/.thumbnails or the ~/.cache/thumbnails directory.

Comment: Super thanks! Tiny (but indeed recovered :) holiday pics now properly backed up. ~/.cache/thumbnails worked for me (Ubuntu 13.10); couldn't find ~/.thumbnails